# How to startMonitoringForRegion for a fixed time period?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

i am trying to run some code if the users enters a region. But only if the reason was stored less than 60min ago. **Any ideas how to check the 'date (created_at)' of a region?**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    // Do sth. if the region was stored less than 60 min ago

}
```

Thanks,
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

`CLRegion` doesn't have a "storage date" property or anything like that, but you could just store the date in the user defaults when you start monitoring the region (e.g. in a dictionary that maps the region's `identifier` to the date/time when you started to monitor it).

Comment: that was my idea too. or just store the date in the identifier.